# Using PHP and a MYSQL database to find results not in another table?

Tags: php, mysql, database

All request records exist within the Request table. They can then be filtered because some also belong in an additional table, either Booking or Declined. Rooms and vwRoomRequest don’t affect this query.
I’m trying to return records which have been ‘declined’, they therefore exist in both the Requests table AND the Declined table and the primary key of these 2 tables will be the same.

In the real query, I’m using group by Request.RequestID because this query returns 2488 results when there are in fact only 17 rows in the Request table!

The main problem (other than the above), is that this query is returning the same result as if the this line of the query were not there : 
    AND Request.RequestID<>BookingID AND Request.RequestID<>Declined.RequestID.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Request , Rooms, Booking, Declined, vwRoomRequest 
WHERE Request.RoomID = Rooms.RoomID 
AND Rooms.RoomID = vwRoomRequest.RoomID
AND Request.RequestID<>BookingID 
AND Request.RequestID<>Declined.RequestID
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to return all requests that have been declined, why not just return all rows from the `Declined` table and `LEFT JOIN` in whatever other tables you need? Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Declined
LEFT JOIN Request ON Declined.RequestID = Request.RequestID
LEFT JOIN Rooms ON Request.RoomID = Rooms.RoomID
LEFT JOIN vmRoomRequest ON Rooms.RoomID = vmRoomRequest.RoomID
```